# Java HTTP Pooling Custom Header

Tags: java, http, http-headers

I was able to implement the HTTP Connection Pooling sample defined on this [website](https://springframework.guru/using-resttemplate-with-apaches-httpclient/). But I want the ability to pass each request a certain unique value and then store that value in a custom header called "Foo".

I understand that I can modify the ClientHttpRequestInterceptor to set a custom header like this...

```
request.getHeaders().add("Foo", "ASDAS");
```

But I want the ability to pass a value so that it's not always ASDAS with each HTTP request. Any help would be helpful because I been pulling my hair for hours now.

---

Side Note: I **need** to use HTTP Pooling due to high data volume rate

Comment: Does it have to be a header? Why not use a request attribute instead?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I already have it built as a parameter because its a GET request. But team is requiring me to use http-header because the data being stored in "Foo" is more or less metadata

Comment: You can wrap the request in a request wrapper. There's a [class](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html) for that in the servlet API. It has the same interface as the request itself. In the wrapper, you can then intercept the `getHeaders()` call and return whatever you want.

Comment: removed the [tag:apache] tag, as this java question is unrelated to Apache httpd (otherwise: please specify). You might want to find a tag that describes better what you're looking for - there are numerous that start with "apache-"

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen So I actually did look into that because ClientHttpRequestInterceptor JavaDocs say that you can wrap it. But I have yet to find decent examples where I can pass a value from RestTemplate. Would you happen to have one? Because maybe I'm being dumb, but I'm not sure how to pass the values from the RestTemplate to the wrapper to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good night of sleep, I got it to work. After reading up more on the RestTemplate JavaDoc, I found out that they have a exchange method which lets you pass custom headers. You don't need to do anything within the ClientHttpRequestInterceptor class

Answer (score 0):

request.getHeaders().add("Foo", "Value");
You can generate Value by other way,for example
MD5("Unique String" + System.currentTimeMillis() + index + ....)
I'm not sure I can solve your problem.